# Why does this function work in some cases, but not others?

Tags: lua

I am trying to write a function to make set r have a symmetric relation if it doesn't already have one (e.g. if it has 2,1 but not 1,2 then it should add in 1,2). I have seeded and it works in most cases but fails in others by not adding all of the pairs that it should have added with seemingly no rhyme or reason to it.

I have checked the other functions the program is using and they all seem to work correctly, so I've narrowed it down to basically just the one function not working but can't figure out why.

```
--these two dictionaries provide the initial set, r.
    r={
     ['ac']=true,
     ['ba']=true,
     ['cd']=true,
     ['ad']=true,
     ['bd']=true,
     ['aa']=true,
     ['ca']=true,
     }
 let={
      ['a']=1,
      ['b']=2,
      ['c']=3,
      ['d']=4     
 }
```

r initially prints out as follows:
(1,3)
(2,1)
(3,4)
(1,4)
(2,4)
(3,1)
(1,1)

---

```
--this function takes r as a parameter and checks the keys for the inverse ordered pair (e.g. if it has an 'ad' key but not 'da', it should add it and then return r as a now symmetric relation.

    function make_symmetric (tab)
        for k in pairs(tab) do
            if not tab[string.sub(k,2,2)..string.sub(k,1,1)] then
               tab[string.sub(k,2,2)..string.sub(k,1,1)]=true
            end
        end
        return tab
     end
```

r then prints out as:
(4,3)
(3,1)
(1,2)
(1,1)
(1,3)
(1,4)
(2,4)
(2,1)
(3,4)

---

As you can see it didn't add in (4,2) and (4,1) like it should have to make the set symmetric, but successfully added in the others.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `make_symmetric` behaves correctly, I believe the error in the function you convert keys to numbers. printing r table gives me this `["ad"] = true;
["da"] = true;
["bd"] = true;
["db"] = true;
["cd"] = true;
["dc"] = true;
["ba"] = true;
["ab"] = true;
["ac"] = true;
["ca"] = true;
["aa"] = true;`

Comment: You are not allowed to ADD NEW KEYS to a table while traversing this table with `pairs`.  Rewrite your program in two steps: 1) create "delta" table and 2) add "delta" table to your table.

Comment: @das It isn't the printer because I can manually check for the keys ['da'] and ['db'] and get nil after the iteration.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I also tried the delta table (creating a local table within the function, adding to that, and returning it to no avail).

Comment: @Kazakh62 - Show your code with delta-table